# handling/compressing large datasets in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, aggregation, materialized-views

In an application at our company we collect statistical data from our servers (load, disk usage and so on). Since there is a huge amount of data and we don't need all data at all times we've had a "compression" routine that takes the raw data and calculates min. max and average for a number of data-points, store these new values in the same table and removes the old ones after some weeks.

Now I'm tasked with rewriting this compression routine and the new routine must keep all uncompressed data we have for one year in one table and "compressed" data in another table. My main concerns now are how to handle the data that is continuously written to the database and whether or not to use a "transaction table" (my own term since I cant come up with a better one, I'm not talking about the commit/rollback transaction functionality).

As of now our data collectors insert all information into a table named `ovak_result` and the compressed data will end up in `ovak_resultcompressed`. But are there any specific benefits or drawbacks to creating a table called `ovak_resultuncompressed` and just use `ovak_result` as a "temporary storage"? `ovak_result` would be kept minimal which would be good for the compressing routine, but I would need to shuffle all data from one table into another continually, and there would be constant reading, writing and deleting in `ovak_result`.

Are there any mechanisms in MySQL to handle these kind of things?

(*Please note:* We are talking about quite large datasets here (about 100 M rows in the uncompressed table and about 1-10 M rows in the compressed table). Also, I can do pretty much what I want with both software and hardware configurations so if you have any hints or ideas involving MySQL configurations or hardware set-up, just bring them on.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading about the [ARCHIVE storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/archive-storage-engine.html).

---

Re your clarification.  Okay, I didn't get what you meant from your description.  Reading more carefully, I see you did mention min, max, and average.

So what you want is a *materialized view* that updates *aggregate calculations* for a large dataset.  Some RDBMS brands such as Oracle have this feature, but MySQL doesn't.

One experimental product that tries to solve this is called **FlexViews** (http://code.google.com/p/flexviews/).  This is an open-source companion tool for MySQL.  You define a query as a view against your raw dataset, and FlexViews continually monitors the MySQL binary logs, and when it sees relevant changes, it updates just the rows in the view that need to be updated.

It's pretty effective, but it has a few limitations in the types of queries you can use as your view, and it's also implemented in PHP code, so it's not fast enough to keep up if you have really high traffic updating your base table.

Comment: Interesting engine, but unfortunately far away from what I need. The lack of indexes will make it quite hard to use since I need to join some tables and I need the update function at least.

To clarify my talk about compression; the "compression" (should call it averaging maybe) I described is done to make it more usable (eg graphical charts get less cluttered when viewing trends over months), not to preserve disk space. Performance is prioritized over disk space.

Comment: FlexViews looks very interesting, and although I'm not yet sure that it is the answer to my problem, both your answers have given me quite a few ideas and help me in the process so I'm calling this an accepted answer. Thanks alot :)

Comment: I'm glad to help.  Good luck with your project!